# Read last character of a text file

Tags: java, file-io, nio

I got this little code snippet which works just fine:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(
                Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath()), Charset.defaultCharset());
if (lines.size() > 0) {
            char c = lines.get(lines.size() - 1).charAt(
                    lines.get(lines.size() - 1).length() - 1); 
}
```

But this uses java.nio package which is not available prior `Java 1.7`.

Now I need a reliable way to accomplish the same with prior Java versions.
Do you have an idea ? The only thing I can think of, is to read the file line by line with a `BufferedReader` and if the reading is complete somehow retrieve the last character from this.

Comment: `RandomAccessFile` would be better so you can seek to the end easily.

Comment: @Bubletan with the problem that of course you can't really "seek to the end", since the way you read characters is entirely dependent on the charset

Comment: @fge Well, assuming that it would be known, of course.

Comment: @Bubletan you fail, however, to account for the fact that some character codings are not fixed byte encodings; and that includes the one primarily used today, that is, UTF-8, where a single code point can require as little as one byte or as many as four!

Comment: @fge If you know the amount of bytes needed to be read, it's possible. Just depends on the way the file is encoded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(still using Java 6 in 2015? Ahwell)

Here is a solution; note that is supposes that you already have a `BufferedReader` open on the file:

```
String line, lastLine = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    lastLine = line;

// obtain the last character from lastLine, as you already do
```

NOTE that this will truthfully return the last (java) *char*, which may not be the last *code point*.

Comment: You probably want to assign an initial value of `null` to `lastLine`, as otherwise it won't be definitely assigned.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll go with this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `java.io.RandomAccessFile` class:

```
private static byte[] readFromFile(String filePath, int position, int size) throws IOException 
{
    RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "r");
    file.seek(position);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
    file.read(bytes);
    file.close();
    return bytes;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you also for your version :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is this

```
    FileReader r = new FileReader("1.txt");
    char[] buf = new char[1024];
    char last = 0;
    for(int n; (n = r.read(buf)) > 0;) {
        last = buf[n - 1];
    }
```